# Display elements in horizontally and vertically (In 1 lines how-many-ever fit, then display in next line)

Tags: android, android-layout

The way in html we can just create ul li elements with ul `{list-style:none}` and li `display:inline-block;` and then the li can be a box, or a photo. And in the result the boxes will render in first line how-many-ever fit and then in second line, and so on..

Example of the same in html: http://jsbin.com/nutufomi/1/

How do we achieve similar result in android.. With horizontal `linearlayout` the elements limit in 1 line.. I cant have horizontal layouts in vertical layout, with each horizontal layout containing fixed number of boxes, I need the number of boxes in one line dynamic, so that with screensize change it changes..

Comment: I cant think of a way to achieve this in single horizontal linearlayout but you could try gridview

Comment: @IllegalArgument Yeah I am okay with using gridview.. Can u guide me how can I can I achieve the requirement using grid view.. Cuz as per my understanding of gridview there also I have to fix number if elements in each row

Comment: You can use `GridView` with , but it won't be "staggered", i..e

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Gridview** for your purposes. Here is a small sample:

```
<GridView 
android:id="@+id/gridView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="8dp"
android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="60dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"    
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

The important properties are **android:stretchMode="columnWidth"** and **android:numColumns="auto_fit"**. You can find a lot of tutorials and posts about gridview.